# Vertically centered text not showing center on mobile devices but showing center on desktop devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a digital clock with html css and js. See here https://ibnul.neocities.org/clock.html

I have made the css code in a way that it should show the text of the clock in the middle of the frame on any kind of devices.
But when I open it on my mobile device, the text does not show in the middle of the frame rather it shows a lot down close to the frames bottom edge. 
And it looks like this image [mobile view where the text does not show in the middle of the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPQhd.jpg)

But the text shows center in the frame on desktop device like this image [desktop view where the text shows in the middle of the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHqWX.png)

Here is the code

```js
function a() {
            var d = new Date(),
                h = d.getHours(),
                m = d.getMinutes(),
                s = d.getSeconds(),
                n = 'pm';
            if (h < 12) {
                n = 'am'
            }
            if (h == 0) {
                h = 12
            }
            if (h > 12) {
                h -= 12
            }
            if (h < 10) {
                h = '0' + h
            }
            if (m < 10) {
                m = '0' + m
            }
            if (s < 10) {
                s = '0' + s
            }
            document.getElementsByClassName('d')[1].textContent = h;
            document.getElementsByClassName('f')[1].textContent = m;
            document.getElementsByClassName('g')[1].textContent = s;
            document.getElementsByClassName('h')[1].textContent = n;
            setTimeout(a, 1000)
        }
        a()
```

```css
        body,
        div,
        p {
            margin: 0px
        }
        .c div,
        .c p {
            line-height: 0.8;
            font-family: x
        }
        
        .c div {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.103)
        }
        
        .c p {
            color: #000
        }
        
        .b {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: rgb(241, 239, 237)
        }
        
        .c {
            display: flex;
            align-items: baseline;
            font-size: calc(75px + 14*((100vw - 320px)/100));
            user-select: none;
            cursor: default;
            border: 3.4px solid #c4c4c4;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: rgba(21, 41, 80, 0.062)
        }
        
        .p {
            position: relative
        }
        
        .q {
            font-size: 1em
        }
        
        .r {
            font-size: inherit
        }
        
        .s {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0
        }
        
        .d {
            padding: 0.1em 0em 0.1em 0.18em
        }
        
        .f {
            padding: 0.1em 0.2em 0.1em 0em
        }
        
        .g {
            padding: 0.1em 0.2em 0.1em 0.2em
        }
        
        .u {
            font-size: 0.6em
        }
        
        .h {
            padding: 0.1em 0.2em 0.1em 0.2em
        }
        
        .v {
            font-size: 0.67em
        }
        
        @media(max-width:500px) {
            .c {
                font-size: calc(60px + 14*((100vw - 320px)/100));
                border: 2.4px solid #c4c4c4
            }
        }
```

```html
    <div class=b>
        <div class=c>
            <div class='d p q'>88
                <p class='d r s'>12</p>
            </div>
            <p class='e q'>:</p>
            <div class='f p q'>88
                <p class='f r s'>00</p>
            </div>
            <div class='g p u'>88
                <p class='g r s'>00</p>
            </div>
            <div class='h p v'>am
                <p class='h s '>am</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I can't catch the exact reason why this is happening so I couldn't fix it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: When I visit your live demo on desktop I see the text not centered. I think `line-height` or `position:absolute` is messing with your alignment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ In order to help you we need to see your code_ Add both relevant HTML and CSS please _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, both in mobile and desktop, the text is close to the bottom and is not centred.

Seems like you are on windows machine where `.woff` font extension renders with some different line-height. You might need to identify the operating system and apply style (line-height) accordingly.

Comment: I have tried .ttf font but it still doesn't show on the center.

Comment: maybe the font has the issue, irrespective of the extension. If I remove the style-rule `font-family: x`, the text is rendered at the center.

Comment: I have found the problem, it is not on my code rather as you said it is the font itself! The font did render on windows device in the center but it didn't on mac, and I only have a windows machine so I couldn't inspect that myself. Your last comment _maybe the font has the issue, irrespective of the extension. If I remove the style-rule font-family: x, the text is rendered at the center_ help me solve the issue. I have changed the font to the full original version and now it's showing in the middle [see](https://ibnul.neocities.org/clock.html). Thanks a lot.